# How to use git to commit read-only file?

Tags: permissions, git, ubuntu-14.04

I create a read-only file (file permission `444`). When I use `git add` and `git commit`, I got a message as below:

```
[master (root-commit) 5b1336e] initial commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a.txt
```

The file permission is changed to `644`.

After I clone that repository, that file's permission is changed to `664`.

How could I let git to keep original permission?

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Git: 1.9.1

Answer (score 6):

Git does not store file permissions [except for the executable bit](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ContentLimitations). I presume Git will simply use your current `umask` to set the access rights on any operations. And there's not much point in version controlling something you can't edit...

It looks like the [`core.fileMode` configuration option](https://schacon.github.io/git/git-config.html) controls this behaviour.

Comment: I think it make sense in the scenario like the file is used as a global config file for a tool. In a project that use that tool, people have stupid script to modify it which will break other projects. And also you still can edit read only file manually and commit the it. So for git, it can track `x` why not do the same thing for `r` and `w`?

Comment: Git is not a deployment tool; you'll be much better off creating a package or installation script which gives files the correct rights on installation. This way you can also handle other file attributes such as for SELinux, and the deployed system won't contain a bunch of files which belong only on the developer desktop (`.git` directory, test files, etc.).